# SQL 2008 blob data unused space cannot be freed

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob, space

Environment: SQL Server 2008 spk1 Enterprise edition.

I have a large table which stores `varbinary` and `blob` data.  If I run the disk usage report in SSMS we see that about a third of the space in our databases (There are hundreds for this application) show as "Unused space" (I do not mean unallocated.)

I've run across a number of solutions from people on the interwebs which do not work.

- `dbcc cleantable`
- Dropping the clustered index and rebuilding it
- Rebuilding all indexes

If I `select * into` another table it rebuilds the table without all the extra cruft.

If I run:

```
SELECT alloc_unit_type_desc, avg_page_space_used_in_percent, record_count,
ghost_record_count FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
(DB_ID(N'Test_dbname'), OBJECT_ID(N'table_name'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED');
```

I receive:

```
alloc_unit_type_desc avg_page_space_used_in_percent record_count ghost_record_count
IN_ROW_DATA          66.7239065974796               12404285     0
IN_ROW_DATA          0.850741289844334              333460       0
IN_ROW_DATA          44.903076352854                80002        0
IN_ROW_DATA          78.5273041759328               374          0
LOB_DATA             64.0441438102298               62248788     0
```

Which I believe demonstrates that there is substantial space allocated.  The question is why can't I reduce this space?   Over the course of hundreds of databases we're talking terabytes of wasted space.

Comment: Can you select the space-related columns from dm_db_index_physical_stats and show them? I want to see the numbers measured in pages, not rows. Also, please run a `DETAILED` scan and post the fragmentation numbers (fragmentation, avg_fragment_size).

Comment: This may be a better question for the Database Administrators forum. http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like a filing system. Selecting into another table writes the used data in hopefully a contiguous chunk in the mdb. Then you change a few blobs here and there, the DBMS quite sensibly wants to keep each blob continuous....

So even if there was a command to square up the table it would basically do what you are doing now, anything else would be asking for it.

The real answer is don't use an RDBMS to store this sort of data.

Comment: Tony are you saying the answer is that there is no way to clean up this table?

Comment: No I'm saying using it will make it messy again. Not to mention cleaning it up means there's no chance of there being any room to work, so it will expand anyway. Like rebuilding an index with a 100% fill factor. RDBMS and blob is a very uneasy combination.